# Bold dynamic type in Swift

Tags: swift, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

[image]

How come for a dynamic font on a `UILabel` where we have the following:

```swift
        artistLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body, compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(legibilityWeight: .regular))
        artistLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        
        trackLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body, compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(legibilityWeight: .bold))
        trackLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

bold and regular look the same? How can I get a true "bold" font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom font for this.

**Step 1:** Add Custom fonts to the project.

[image]

**Step 2:** Add these fonts under "Fonts Provided by application" key in info.plist file

[image]

**Step 3:** Use it as below.

For Bold font:

```
artistLabel.font = UIFont(name:"ArchSans-Bold", size: fontSize)
```

For Regular Font:

```
artistLabel.font = UIFont(name:"ArchSans", size: fontSize)
```

Comment: Can't I use the system font?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.
For Bold:
artistLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
For Regular
artistLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

Answer (score 8):

> bold and regular look the same?

You make this statement because I think you misuse the element to pass in the incoming parameter `compatibleWith` of the `preferredFont` method.
You have provided a `UITraitCollection` element as desired and that's why your code compile.
That's great  but **this trait must be a content size category** to be well understood by the system ⟹ [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor/1771750-preferredfontdescriptor).

You should have used the specified method this way for instance:

```
artistLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body,
                                        compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(preferredContentSizeCategory: .large))
```

> How can I get a true "bold" font?

You can use the code provided by @Ritupal that is efficient  or you can try the following one extracted from a WWDC 2020 video *([The details of UI typography](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10175/?time=1050))* to get a more emphasized text style:

```
if let artistDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .body).withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold) {
        
        artistLabel.font = UIFont(descriptor: artistDescriptor,
                                  size: 0.0)
    }
```

Even if a solution has already been provided, I deemed it important to complement this answer to explain why your initial code didn't work while bringing another way to emphasize text with bold trait.